# Remove an item from localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I'm trying to make, a simple To-Do list in jQuery and I've ran into a problem. This is my first time trying to use `localStorage`. So after making structure for my To-Do list, I wanted to see my items when I refresh page. So first I added this line in my JS:

```
localStorage.setItem("todolist", $('#todoList').html());
```

Then I added

```
$('#todoList').html(localStorage.getItem("todolist"));
```

And this part was working fine but I wanted to another line on my `deleteListItem()` function for deleting my To-Do items from storage. This was the line I added:

```
localStorage.removeItem("todolist", $('#todoList').html());
```

After adding this line I deleted my whole `<ul>` element from browser. Is there a way to reverse this also is there a way to make my To-Do list to work properly with `localStorage`.

Here is mine JSBin so you better understand what I'm doing:

> http://jsbin.com/ciyufi/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: The `storage.removeItem` should receive only 1 parameter. Try `localStorage.removeItem("todolist")`.

Comment: Is the concern to save memory? localstorage works like a map, if you set another value with the exact same key, it will overwrite what is existing in there. you don't have to remove an item before setting a new one.

Comment: @devilfart My ToDo list is making new "li" elements and I want them to stay as they were when I refresh browser. For example if I add three tasks and delete one on refresh I wan't it to stay like that.

Answer (score 1):

You should first check if something already exists in the localStorage:

```
if (localStorage.getItem("todolist") != null) {
    $('#todoList').html(localStorage.getItem("todolist")); // This reads items in our local storage
}
```

Check this update:
http://jsbin.com/damedomepi/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: At times where you know the expected output for a function on failure is `null`, feel free to use the strict comparison operator `!==`. It wouldn't change much for this particular case, but it's a good habit to have!